# SQLite3 - Why won't the referential data delete?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am really new to SQLite so please forgive my ignorance and silly mistakes.

**Brief**

I currently have 2 tables, one is the main table which holds company names, the second holds articles relating to that company.

**The Schema**

*Table 1*

```
Companies(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO INCREMENT, tick TEXT, business_name TEXT)
```

*Table 2*

```
Articles(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
         tick TEXT, thedate TEXT, thetime TEXT, title TEXT, link TEXT, 
         FOREIGN KEY(tick) REFERENCES Companies(tick) ON DELETE CASCADE)
```

Why isn't this working? Once I delete a tick out of the `Companies` table, it doesn't delete all the items out of the `Articles` table.

Comment: Why do you reference ``Companies.tick`` with your FKey rather than ``Companies.id``? Is ``Companies.tick`` guaranteed to be unique?

Comment: Yeah the tick, short for stock ticker is going to be unique and with validation can't be added again, however, making the FKey Companies.id to make it function wouldn't be a problem, or if it was better practice. I am open to learn

Comment: Generally speaking, yes. Basically, the point of a `PRIMARY KEY` is to identify the minimum subset of information to uniquely identify a row in the table (basically, the unique **invariants** of that row that define it as an entity and not some other entity). Foreign Keys should, in a Many-One relation, always reference the Primary Key of the parent entry. If `tick` is truly a unique-invariant, you could theoretically consider it to be part of the Primary Key of the `Companies` table. However, doing queries against string values is slow. So likely leaving it out is a good idea.

Comment: But how could FOREIGN KEY(tick) REFERENCES Companies(id) if tick is a string and id is an integer? Sorry to hound you with questions but you are clearly a thought leader

Comment: It doesn't. The ``FOREIGN KEY`` should be called ``company_id`` or similar, and be an integer. To load the ticker value, you do a ``JOIN`` query. See the general idea of [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) and some tutorials on [joins](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_using_joins.ht) in SQLite

Comment: As a great example for why you would definitely **not** want ``tick`` to be part of the PKey or what defines your FKey: Ticks on the stock market are only guaranteed to be unique *at any given time*. If a company goes out of business, a new company could come up and use the same Tick. Or rarely a company can change it if needed. You would now have no way of differentiating between these two companies on the ``Articles`` side, nor would you be able to insert the new ``Company`` without first deleting the old one since ``Tick`` is declared to be unique. Neither of these is the result you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to [enable foreign key support](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html) for every database connection.

> Assuming the library is compiled with foreign key constraints enabled,
>   it must still be enabled by the application at runtime, using the
>   PRAGMA foreign_keys command. For example:
>
> sqlite> PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;

Here's an example session. Note the `unique` constraint on "tick".

```
sqlite> create table companies(
   ...>   id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
   ...>   tick TEXT unique, 
   ...>   business_name TEXT
   ...> );
sqlite> 
sqlite> create table articles(
   ...>   id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
   ...>   tick TEXT, 
   ...>   thedate TEXT, 
   ...>   thetime TEXT, 
   ...>   title TEXT, 
   ...>   link TEXT, 
   ...>   FOREIGN KEY(tick) REFERENCES Companies(tick) ON DELETE CASCADE
   ...> );
sqlite> 
sqlite> insert into companies values (1, 'aaa', 'AAA company');
sqlite> insert into articles values (1, 'bbb', '2014-01-01', '08:00', 'Some Title', 'some link');
```

That insert statement succeeded, because although we declared a foreign key constraint, we did not yet enable it. Let's get rid of that data . . .

```
sqlite> delete from companies;
sqlite> delete from articles;
```

enable foreign key constraints . . .

```
sqlite> pragma foreign_keys=on;
```

and try again.

```
sqlite> insert into companies values (1, 'aaa', 'AAA company');
sqlite> insert into articles values (1, 'aaa', '2014-01-01', '08:00', 'Some Title', 'some link');
sqlite> select * from articles where tick = 'aaa';
1|aaa|2014-01-01|08:00|Some Title|some link
```

There's our article.

```
sqlite> delete from companies where tick = 'aaa';
sqlite> select * from articles where tick = 'aaa';
sqlite>
```

Nothing returned, because `on delete cascade` removed the referencing row.

Comment: If foreign key support had been enabled, the database would have complained because of the [missing indexes](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_indexes).

Comment: @Mike Sherrill 'Cat Recall' That was exactly the problem - I wasn't enabling FKey support for EVERY connection! You're my hero